# PCF8591 I2C Problems on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, adc, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am using 3 PCF8591 ADC connected via i2c to a raspberry pi.

At first all 3 of the ADC worked. All of a sudden I started having issued with them. Occasionally one of the i2c devices stops showing up (i2cdetect -y 1). And now when reading some devices they show up and connect however they always read 0. I attributed this to a damaged ADC so I replaced it but got the same issue. Sometimes is works, sometimes it doesn't. Often after first starting it will work for about 10 seconds then start reading 0.

[image: PCB]

This is the layout of the PCB I used. I realised I had forgotten the pull up resistors so I jumpered 2 4.3k resistors from the SDA and SCL pins to 3.3V pin.
I haven't had heaps of experience with PCB layouts so I'm wondering if I did something very wrong that is causing the i2c to not work all the time outside of the two pull up resistors I missed. I do not want to get another batch of PCBs made if I have made some other big mistake.

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

def readADCPin(pin):
    bus.write_byte(address,pin)
    x = 0
    value = 0
    numReadings = 4
    tot = 0
    while x < numReadings:
        value += bus.read_byte(address)
        x+=1
    value /= numReadings
    return value
```

This is the code I am using. As you can see I'm using SMbus to talk to the different devices.

Comment: Eliminate some options. Did you try another RPi or other i2c host? Did you try another board? Software from scratch?

Comment: I reflashed the OS to make sure. I am also pretty sure I used a different RPi but there is always a chance I got mixed up and grabbed the one I was already using. Ill try again with another RPi in a second and let you know how I go.

Comment: Update: I have also tried a new RPi. Same thing. Works for a little but then reads 0.

Comment: If the problem would not been solved already, I would have suggested to double check the soldering of the I2C pins of the 40 pins connector .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So its been solved. The issue was with addressing each ADC. I grounded different address pins like normal however I left the unused ones floating. So all I needed to do was tie the unused address pins to VCC.

Comment: Congrats! Do accept your own answer as well.